# unable to position text under form

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner in web development . I'm working on ap roject where I have a form that when I fill I move on to the next step of the process . However my title for the next step is positioned far below my form I have made when I want it to be positioned left right under it . 
My code :

```css
.form-area{

display:block;
position:relative;
left:50%;
margin-top:270px;
transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
width:500px;
height:550px;
box-sizing:border-box; 
background:rgb(0,0,0,0.5);
padding:40px; 
border-radius:50px; 
 
}


#step3{
 
position:relative;
margin-top:0px; 
text-align:left;
 
}
```

```html
<div class = "form-area" id = "forma">  //my form 
 
 <form  class = "sign-form" > 
  
   <div class = "form-container">
  
        <h1> Enter purchase data below : </h1>   
  
        <label for "dieythinsi" >  Address Name</label>
           <input type = "text" placeholder = "Enter address name " id = "address" name = "addr" required/> 
  </label>
   
  
  
        <label for "arithmos-dieyth" >  Address Number</label>
           <input type = "text" placeholder = "Enter address number " id = "address-num" name = "addnum" required/> 
        </label>

  
        <label for "perioxi" > Region </label>
  
          <input type = "text" placeholder = "Enter region "id = "region" name = "reg" required/> 
        </label>
  
        
        <label for "taxidromikos"> Postal Code</label>
            <input type = "text"  placeholder = "(5 digit number)"  id = "postal-code" name = "postcode" required/> 
        </label>
  
  <div id = "delivery-expenses">
      
   Delivery Expenses at 2$
  
  </div>
  
      <div id ="express-delivery">
       <span id = "e-text">Express Delivery ? (+6$) (if total purchase more than 30$ then it's free !)</span><input type="checkbox" id = "exp-box" value="express" onclick="expressfunc()" id="e-delivery">
        </div>
  
   </div>
   
       <button type = "button" id = "c" class = "cancelbtn"  onclick = "goback()">Go back</button> 
       <button  type = "button" id = "n" class="continuebtn" onclick = "return checkdata()">Next</button>
    
 
  
  </form>
 
 </div>
 
 //the text under the form that I want to position left and close to the form 
 
   <h1 id = "step3"> Step 3 : Select way of payment to finish. </h1>  <br/>
```

I would appreciate your guidance with helping me to solve this issue . Thank you in advance . (for any clarifications feel free to ask )

Comment: Just use <br> after every <input> tag. Like this: 

<label for "taxidromikos"> Postal Code</label>
            <input type = "text"  placeholder = "(5 digit number)"  id = "postal-code" name = "postcode" required/> 
        </label>
<br>

Comment: @HassaanAli could you please specify your solution ?The problem is under my form not inside it

Comment: @Hassaan, look at the end of his HTML there's another header. THat's what he's talking about. He's not talking about the form input elements and labels

Comment: What is causing large space before "step 3" is the transform:translate(-50%,-50%);. Basically you are telling the browser to draw .form-area 270px from the top, and have a height of 550px, then you move the content with the transform. This results in the next block (step 3) to be 820px from the top (270 + 550). I suggest that you remove the transform and center the .form-area with margin: 0 auto;

Comment: @ppablo so I just have to delete it ?

Comment: @VasilisSkentos you can remove it and put margin: 0 auto; instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spacing is due to the `transform` rule in your CSS.

I removed it and added a margin auto for the block to display horizontally centered

```css
.form-area{

display:block;
position:relative;
margin:270px auto 0;
width:500px;
height:550px;
box-sizing:border-box; 
background:rgb(0,0,0,0.5);
padding:40px; 
border-radius:50px; 
 
}


#step3{
 
position:relative;
margin-top:0px; 
text-align:left;
 
}
```

```html
<div class = "form-area" id = "forma">  //my form 
 
 <form  class = "sign-form" > 
  
   <div class = "form-container">
  
        <h1> Enter purchase data below : </h1>   
  
        <label for "dieythinsi" >  Address Name</label>
           <input type = "text" placeholder = "Enter address name " id = "address" name = "addr" required/> 
  </label>
   
  
  
        <label for "arithmos-dieyth" >  Address Number</label>
           <input type = "text" placeholder = "Enter address number " id = "address-num" name = "addnum" required/> 
        </label>

  
        <label for "perioxi" > Region </label>
  
          <input type = "text" placeholder = "Enter region "id = "region" name = "reg" required/> 
        </label>
  
        
        <label for "taxidromikos"> Postal Code</label>
            <input type = "text"  placeholder = "(5 digit number)"  id = "postal-code" name = "postcode" required/> 
        </label>
  
  <div id = "delivery-expenses">
      
   Delivery Expenses at 2$
  
  </div>
  
      <div id ="express-delivery">
       <span id = "e-text">Express Delivery ? (+6$) (if total purchase more than 30$ then it's free !)</span><input type="checkbox" id = "exp-box" value="express" onclick="expressfunc()" id="e-delivery">
        </div>
  
   </div>
   
       <button type = "button" id = "c" class = "cancelbtn"  onclick = "goback()">Go back</button> 
       <button  type = "button" id = "n" class="continuebtn" onclick = "return checkdata()">Next</button>
    
 
  
  </form>
 
 </div>
 
 //the text under the form that I want to position left and close to the form 
 
   <h1 id = "step3"> Step 3 : Select way of payment to finish. </h1>  <br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are unwanted CSS styles that you can remove from your code and make it simpler. Left: 50% would not center your container. You can either use `margin: 0 auto` or add `margin-left: -250px` to your absolutely positioned div along with `left: 50%`.

This might be helpful: https://jsfiddle.net/d4pqc85w/1/